# Wordpress specific content

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day to all,

I'm new in wordpress. I want to ask on how to display my page content in different div. But when I try this code. It won't display anything, my page won't even load. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

`<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/wordpress/?page_id=5'): ?>`

```
   <div style="width:960px; float:left;min-height:290px;word-wrap: break-word">
     <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>   
     <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
   </div>
```

`<?php else: ?>`

```
   <div style="width:640px; float:left;min-height:290px;word-wrap: break-word">
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
   </div>
```

`<?php endif;?>`

Comment: Looks like there's a missing `<?php endif; ?>` at the end...  Turn on `display_errors`, and you'll see syntax errors. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I edited your question and then added the last line `<?php endif; ?>`.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo But that might be _the reason_ the OP's page doesn't load.  You can't add it until the OP confirms it wasn't already there.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to place endif but still, my problem is the same.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, you are right, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the theme files, copy and paste the `page.php`, rename the duplicate file to `page-about.php`, where `about` is the slug of the page. Similarly you can have any number of `page` duplicates.

To find what is the slug of a page, go to the `page editing` area, `Screen Option` > `View Slug`.

Comment: After that? How am I be able to try the page. To have different divs. Thanks!

Comment: You can edit the duplicated `page-about.php` like you want, give different classes, id etc to any div you like. And next time you load the said page, wordpress will load your custom page automatically.

Comment: @BoyPasmo So, technically you can do anything you want on the duplicated page. I hope I'm clear about what I said.